# How to count distinct date items in a timestamp field in Mongoose/NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use Mongoose in my NodeJS, and I have a collection with documents that look like this -

```
var SomeSchema = new Schema({
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    },
    some_item: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

The `date` field contains date with the time component (for example, `2014-05-09 09:43:02.478Z`). How do I get a count of **distinct** items for a given date, say `2014-05-08`?

**EDIT:** Ideally, I would like to get a count of records for each distinct date.

Comment: As per mongoose documentation .
Model.distinct(field, conditions, callback);

Comment: What would my conditions be?

Comment: Distinct is not a good idea. It is just a wrapper around mapReduce and therefore runs a lot slower than the aggregation framework alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is usage of the aggregation framework with the [**`aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) command, at least for finding one date as you ask:

```js
SomeSchema.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": {
            "date": { 
                "$gte": new Date("2014-05-08"), "$lt": new Date("2014-05-09")
            }
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$some_item",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {
        // do something with result

    }
);
```

If you are specifically looking for "counts" over several dates then you can do something like this:

```js
SomeSchema.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": {
            "date": { 
                "$gte": new Date("2014-05-01"), "$lt": new Date("2014-06-01")
            }
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "year":  { "$year": "$date" },
                "month": { "$month": "$date" },
                "day":   { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }
            }
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {
        // do something with result

    }
);
```

And that gives you "per day" grouping. Look for the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) in the documentation if you wish to take this further.

Comment: Fantastic. Will I be able to do this for all unique dates too? Or would I have to select each date in a loop and then count distinct records for that date?

Comment: Good answer.  Neil, you forgot your `_id` definition in your second example.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thankyou, Thankyou once again. How are you not a moderator yet?

Comment: @GPX I think there is an edit in there that shows how to find singular day boundaries and group by them